# Which are the non-relativistic and relativistic physical quantities?

Tags: general-relativity, relativity

I would like to know whether there are ANY physical quantities, which are not influenced by relativity, in other words, in any frame of reference one gets the same result if one measures them.
If there are, then can you give a list of them and/or a rule of thumb, how to know which they are?

An example is as below, does speed really not distort gravitational field?
https://www.quora.com/Does-speed-affect-the-gravity-applied-on-the-moving-object

Here the first answer states: "If we are talking about the gravity of another body on the object, then NO." (So speed does not affect the gravity.)

Physical quantities list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Physical_quantities

For the moderators: 
I have updated the question as far as I can.
This question does not exist yet, and in physics nothing can be too broad. As Einstein demonstrated even the most basic laws of physics (Newton's laws) can be defied, and have to be rewritten to fit all possible use cases. On top of that I also gave a specific example.

Comment: Yes, and such quantities are called [Lorentz invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_scalar) in special relativity or just *scalar inariants* in general relativity. For example the [Kretschmann scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kretschmann_scalar) is an invariant in GR.